# Camel ProducerTemplate possible memory leak

Tags: apache-camel

To some extent, this is a bit of a shot in the dark, but we have a process that dramatically slows down over the course of a day. We've found everything running on Fuse begins to drag, but only when we've been running a specific process. Running JProfiler, I found there to be a memory usage increase over time marked on org.apache.camel.ProducreTemplate.send.

So my main question is, is there something I'm missing with the way we are using the ProducerTemplate here that is incorrect/could be causing this issue?

```
Exchange foo = new DefaultExchange(getCamelContext(), ExchangePattern.InOnly);
foo.getIn().setBody(obj);
Route r = exchange.getContext().getRoute("do_something_fun");
ProducerTemplate template = exchange.getContext().createProducerTemplate();
template.send(r.getEndpoint(), foo);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you shouldn't create a ProducerTemplate on each request as is described here: http://camel.apache.org/why-does-camel-use-too-many-threads-with-producertemplate.html

However, because I don't have the complete picture of your application you could have a situation where you cannot reuse it but then you must remember to close it when you're done with it.